# How can I find out which tables and stored procedures a database user has accessed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to find out which tables and stored procedures a user *has* accessed? Note that this is what the user *has* actually accessed and not what they *can* access.

For tables, is it also possible to know whether the access was read or write?

I would like this information to determine which database privileges can be removed for this user.

Comment: Please before down voting can you leave a comment with some constructive feedback. I've tried to be clear and concise with my requirements but do let me know if I can expand on anything and I will edit the question. I Googled around for some time and could not find anyone asking the same question.

Comment: Check out ApexSQL Audit, I'm a developer and don't use the audit tools myself, but my DBA says that specific tool (Apex has a ton) allows auditing of all changes, and can log individual SELECT and EXEC statements too. We aren't actually doing that so I can't say how well it works, but he said it was an option.

Comment: @RobertSheahan thanks for this. I'm going to first investigate what SQLGeorge has posted as an answer as that's built-in so there are no costs involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not for the past. On SQL Server 2014, you can setup specific monitoring tasks (called "audititing"), so that from now on you can collect the access data you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it will do the trick. Is it [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-auditing-server-database-audit-specifications/) that you're referring to? It suggests this was available from SQL Server 2008 so just making sure it's what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes, exactly this is it. You can also find documentation on Microsoft sites. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017